# MySQL : error 1217 on DROP TABLE. Foreign key refering on its own primary key. ON DELETE CASCADE is on

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sql-drop

I'm trying this query

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Core;`

on a table created with this query

```
CREATE TABLE Core (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,

    title varchar(512),
    kind ENUM('User', 'Organisation', 'Channel', 'Collection', 'Text', 'Picture', 'Sound', 'Video', 'UserGroup'),
    is_activated BOOLEAN DEFAULT true,
    date_created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    date_updated DATETIME,
    date_augmented DATETIME,

    author_core BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (author_core) REFERENCES Core(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

but i get the error `#1217 - A foreign key constraint fails`.

I know the dirty workaround that is disabling the foreign key check with
`SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` but i'm still wondering why the `ON DELETE CASCADE` of the field `author_core` is not doing its job.

Comment: seems to me that you are referring to the core table  ..  (same table you are delete with a delete cascade)  ..  could be your constraisn si for anothers  table??

Comment: Creating and immediately dropping this table works fine for me which suggest this table is a referenced table somewhere else in your db, This may help you find it https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102371/mysql-how-to-check-foreign-keys-related-to-a-table

Comment: Thank you @P.Salmon ! I indeed had other tables referring to  the `Core` one that didn't have `ON DELETE CASCADE` on their foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is another table refering to the `Core` table. You can get all refering keys of the other tables with following query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'Core' AND TABLE_NAME <> 'Core'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01a7fa12b6a6720e1e98103d0a62529c)

You have to remove these found constraints first before `DROP TABLE`.